# Firebase data comparison swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

hi I'm new to swift and i'm using firebase in my app. i want to get all the data under a child from firebase database and compare it with an already existing array to find the missing values and load them in tableview i had added the code i use to perform this and in that the for loop is called every time when new child is found and i want to perform that for loop after getting all the values from the firebase database. is there any way to perform this or is there any way to know whether the firebase had retrieved all the data. Thanks in advance

```
func fetchUsers()
{
    ingredientMasterArr.removeAll()
    refhandle1 = ref.child("ingredients").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock:
        { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String : String]
        {
            let ingredients = IngredientsClass()
            ingredients.id = dictionary["id"]
            ingredients.ingredient_name = dictionary["ingredient_name"]
           // ingredients.category
            ingredientMasterArr.append(ingredients)
        }
            FilteredIngMasterArr.removeAll()
                let temp = IngredientsClass()
                for MasterID in ingredientMasterArr
                {
                    if (ShopIngKeysArr .contains(MasterID.id!)){ 
                    print("if",MasterID.ingredient_name)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("else",MasterID.ingredient_name)
                        temp.id = MasterID.id
                        temp.ingredient_name = MasterID.ingredient_name
                        FilteredIngMasterArr.append(temp)
                    }
                }
            self.tbl_ingMaster.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the **.Value** event type  instead of **.ChildAdded** should give you all the results at once:

```
    refhandle1 = ref.child("ingredients").observeEventType(.Value, ...
```

Read the firebase [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-event-types) on retrieving data for more details.